# Mutate an array order using only swap

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Assume you have two arrays, a and b. a's data is completely hidden from you. The only operation you can perform on a is to swap two elements. b's data is completely exposed and mutable.

The value of b at position i indicates the destination for the value stored in a[i]. That is, if b[3] = 7, we want to move the value in a[3] to be in a[7]. I'm trying to write an algorithm which mutates array a according to the information in array b using only swap operations on a (and preferably linear time and constant space).  Just as an example:

```
if   a  = { a b c d e f }
and  b  = { 1 3 2 0 5 4 }
then a' = { d a c b f e }
(ie, a[i] = a'[b[i]])
```

I tried a naive approach of iterating through b and merrily doing a.Swap(i, b[i]), all the while whistling, but that turns out to end up writing over itself and moving data that's already in the right place (as you might guess).

Edit: This really must be linear time. It's for a parallel sorting algorithm, so speed is paramount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in Go:

```
for i := 0; i != len(b); i++ {
    for b[i] != i {
        a.Swap(i, b[i])
        b.Swap(i, b[i])
    }
}
```

This may not immediately look O(n), but notice that

- every a.Swap() puts at least one element of a into its final position

  - once an element is in its final position it never gets swapped again
  - so there are at most n swaps
- the `b[i] != i` test is done once for each swap and one extra time for each i

  - so there are at most 2n tests

As you can see, this algorithm is O(n) on time and O(1) on space.

Comment: Actually, it turns out this doesn't work. I tried it on a test case where I knew the ordering was correct and it didn't produce the desired ordering. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the elements of b in ascending order and while swapping the elements of b, swap those in a too. For example, using bubble sort:

```
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
for(int j=0;j<b.length-i-1;j++){
if(b[j+1]<b[j]){
// swap b[j+1] and b[j]
// swap a[j] and a[j+1]
}
}
}
```

Comment: Technically you're right, but I really do need this to be linear.  A little bit of background: this is for a parallel sorting algorithm's merge phase, and so it's sort of pointless to do parallel sorting and then finish it off with quadratic bubble sort.

Comment: Also, b's elements are the indices of a, so sorting them would just result in b[i] = i